# Unable to work with wifi after suspend

Tags: mx-linux

I am using MX Linux 21.3 on Thinkpad T440P. I cannot work with wifi after system wakes up from sleep. I have tried the troubleshooting methods listed on Arch Wiki and Gentoo Wiki - that is, configuring -

```
#/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi powersave=0 
options iwlmvm power_scheme=1
```

but this does not solve the problem

```
#/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

solves the issue at the cost of throttling my wifi bandwidth to 1/5 and is not ideal.

Following is my `dmesg | iwlwifi` from a fresh reboot

```
[    8.443456] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
[    8.443731] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    8.443759] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwl-debug-yoyo.bin (-2)
[    8.673603] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    8.696335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: base HW address: 5c:51:4f:93:b0:4d
```

Following is my `dmesg | iwlwifi` after waking from suspend

```
[  147.525614] (NULL device *): firmware: direct-loading firmware iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
[  167.697051] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Queue 11 is active on fifo 1 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [108, 244] HW [108, 244] FH TRB=0x0c010b07b
[  167.697143] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Microcode SW error detected.  Restarting 0x2000000.
[  167.697297] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  167.697301] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Status: 0x00000040, count: 6
[  167.697304] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 17.3216344376.0 7260-17.ucode
[  167.697308] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000084 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UNKNOWN       
[  167.697311] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00800634 | trm_hw_status0
[  167.697315] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[  167.697317] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000B30 | branchlink2
[  167.697320] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000164C0 | interruptlink1
[  167.697324] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000164C0 | interruptlink2
[  167.697326] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | data1
[  167.697329] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000080 | data2
[  167.697332] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x07030000 | data3
[  167.697335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x20814859 | beacon time
[  167.697338] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xFF4C77B9 | tsf low
[  167.697341] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000001 | tsf hi
[  167.697344] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[  167.697346] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x011E875C | time gp2
[  167.697349] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | uCode revision type
[  167.697352] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000011 | uCode version major
[  167.697355] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xBFB58538 | uCode version minor
[  167.697358] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000144 | hw version
[  167.697361] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x40489204 | board version
[  167.697364] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0B6C001C | hcmd
[  167.697366] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0xA4022002 | isr0
[  167.697369] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x01800000 | isr1
[  167.697372] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000000A | isr2
[  167.697375] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0040FCC4 | isr3
[  167.697378] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[  167.697380] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00004110 | last cmd Id
[  167.697383] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | wait_event
[  167.697386] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000080 | l2p_control
[  167.697389] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00012030 | l2p_duration
[  167.697392] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0000003F | l2p_mhvalid
[  167.697395] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x000000CE | l2p_addr_match
[  167.697398] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000007 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[  167.697400] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x15041745 | timestamp
[  167.697403] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x0034C0D8 | flow_handler
[  167.697427] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[  167.697443] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[  167.697459] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[  167.697474] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[  167.697490] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[  167.697505] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[  167.697521] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[  167.697536] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[  167.697551] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[  167.697566] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  167.697582] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[  167.697597] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[  167.697612] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: 0x00000000 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[  167.697629] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 2 fired.
```

I would be happy to provide any additional information requested, please help me diagnose this issue if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating `/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf` and adding

`options cfg80211 cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz=Y`

as suggested on gentoo wiki (https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Iwlwifi#Troubleshooting)
solves the issue.